# confused about error using lambda function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, lambda

```
#to add and multiply numbers using lambda in python
a=int(input("a number: "))
b=int(input("another number: "))
print("the sum is {}".format(lambda a,b:a+b))
print("the multiple is {}".format(lambda a,b:a*b))
```

i tried to add and multiply two numbers using lambda but i don't know why it shows error like this.I am a beginner to programming 
the error is :

```
the sum is <function <lambda> at 0x000001B6BF941B88>
the multiple is <function <lambda> at 0x000001B6BF893798>
```

​

​

Comment: because `lambda` is a function. You need to actually **call** it to get a value... why are you using `lambda` here? You could do `(lambda a,b: a+b)(a,b)` but that's just a clumsy way of doing `a + b`...

Comment: What are the lambdas *for*? Just use `a+b` and `a*b`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create a function, but don't actually call it. You can change this in two ways: call the lambda or don't use a lambda function. In this case the second would be better, but if you just want to learn about lambda functions you might use the first.

```py
print("the sum is {}".format((lambda a,b:a+b)(a, b)))
print("the multiple is {}".format((lambda a,b:a*b)(a, b)))
```

The change I made was to replace the lambda with `(lambda a,b:a+b)(a, b)`

or just remove the lambda

```py
print("the sum is {}".format(a+b))
print("the multiple is {}".format(a*b))
```

This would be the better option in this case.

Answer (score 1):

[`lambda`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) is the way of writing anonymous function but they are still functions you need to call them.

```
a=int(input("a number: "))
b=int(input("another number: "))
print("the sum is {}".format((lambda a,b:a+b)(a,b)))
print("the multiple is {}".format((lambda a,b:a*b)(a,b)))
```

Output:

```
a number: 1
another number: 2
the sum is 3
the multiple is 2
```

Comment: thanks for the help, it was my first stack question ,so i am very happy to get help i did not even expect.

Answer (score 1):

There is no error in your output. Since `lambda` is a function, when you print it you see `<function <lambda> at 0x000001B6BF941B88>`.

If you want to invoke it, try:

```
a=int(input("a number: "))
b=int(input("another number: "))
sum_func = lambda a,b:a+b
product_func = lambda a,b:a*b
print("the sum is {}".format(sum_func(a,b)))
print("the multiple is {}".format(product_func(a,b)))
```

Comment: thanks a lot,it sank to my mind now, i thought using lambda like that would already mean i called the lambda function but i get it now.

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Try storing it in a variable.

```
    #to add and multiply numbers using lambda in python
    a=int(input("a number: "))
    b=int(input("another number: "))
    add = lambda a,b:a+b
    mult = lambda a,b:a*b
    print("the sum is {}".format(add(a,b)))
    print("the multiple is {}".format(mult(a,b)))
```